# How to create a client_id and client_secret for API authentication?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0

I want to implement authentication from machine to machine. I am thinking of assigning an API a user a client_secret and client_id which API 1 will use to trade in for a JWT access token.

Am I able to just create 2 unique strings for the secret and the ID and store them against the user in the database?

Something along the lines of this:

```
import { randomUUID } from "crypto";
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const saltRounds = 10;

const client_id = randomUUID();
const client_secret = randomUUID();

const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(saltRounds);
const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(client_secret, salt);

// store hash in database
// have API store client_secret and client_id as environment variables
```

The client secret / id can then be used to verify the API upon incoming requests?

Comment: Yes, as far as they are unique for each client, it's all good.

Answer (score 1):

```
function generate() {
  let ret = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    const newrand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4026531840) + 268435456; 
    ret += newrand.toString(16);
  }
  return ret;
}


function convert(id) {
  let ret = "";
  for (let j = 0; j < 22; j++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
      const code = id[i].charCodeAt() + id[(i + 1) % 64].charCodeAt();
      ret += String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(code % 93) + 33);
    }
    id = ret;
    ret = "";
  }
  return id;
}

const id = generate();
console.log({ "client-id": id, "client-secret": convert(id) });
```

Answer (score 0):

A more standard option might be to just forward a user token from machine to machine, as described in this [IAM Primer](https://curity.io/resources/learn/iam-primer/) article.

One possible problem with what you are doing is that you are storing a long lived credential for a user that can be used to access resources without the user's consent.

Depending on the scenario this could be bad from a security viewpoint, since if a malicious party got hold of a user's client ID and secret they could operate as the user and the downstream API has no way of knowing.

Comment: Even if the secret can be refreshed by the user? Is this not how aws iam users work? They have a set of ids and secrets which can be renewed as needed?

Comment: If the user is involved in lifetimes of tokens - and permissions match those of the app then it is fine. Though forwarding tokens is simpler if that is possible in your setup.